# Effect of `Super` keyword in Exception subclasses

Tags: java, super

```
public class AccountException extends Exception {
    public AccountException(String str) {
      super(str);
     }
   }
```

This is first class in an example programme. What I didn't understand is that why we use super keyword . I know with extends this class from exception class but I do not understand to create method for exception . What will happen when we catch exception ?

I got my question's answer 
 super just call  the method  Exception(String message) to
Constructs a new exception with the specified detail message.
 and this is an example of making our own exception class.

Comment: How do you think `super` is related to the exception handling?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this class extends from exception that's why I think it's related with exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with Exception.

Classes are there so that you can either use them or (in most cases) extend them to make it more useful for your own benefit. Exception is just another class in standard Java libraries and depending on what kind of Exception you are trying to model, it could either be Checked or Unchecked. Read about Exceptions in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html).

"Super" keyword usage has been a popular topic in SO and other Java programmer's site. I won't pollute this thread by repeating the words again. In summary, "You want subclass, you need `super` - Need not, use not".

What happens if you catch an exception - well, using `try{...} catch(Exception e)` block you are actually catching Exception object. Lets assume your own exception class is called "DontKnowException". If you do the following:

```
try {
    // My code

} catch (Exception e) {
   // Print stack trace
   // Do whatever you want using "Exception" object e
}
```

If you look at the code carefully, where are you saying that you are catching "DontKnowException" object? The answer is - nowhere. But are you catching "Exception" object - yes you are. A worldly (may be stupid) example - "Your grandpa has a bike, but doesn't have a car. Your dad has a bike and a car. Grandpa, can I have your car? No I don't have one."

As the Java SO users will also agree, you DONT need to do try-catch if your exception is "Unchecked" category. So why bother using super at all if your exception is "Unchecked"?? may be good practice then?

If you insist on writing your own Exception class, I strongly suggest that you understand whether you are handling unchecked/checked exception. Once you write your class, try and catch your Exception class object, not superclass Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Using `super` calls the superclass constructor. This has nothing to do with exceptions.